# How convert hours and minutes into minutes using javascript?

Tags: javascript

[image]I need to convert hours and minutes(30mins, 65mins) into minutes in a dropdown using javascript! If it's only 30 minutes, display as 30mins, if then 65mins, display 1hr 05mins in the text of a dropdown and value as 65 in value property! I tried some code! On the right side of the picture, it gives the value 1hr60mins not 2hrs! In the code at last line, I just console the object,

```js
var tObj = [
  {"hr": 0, "min": 30, "inMin": 0, "value": "" },
  {"hr": 0, "min": 45, "inMin": 0, "value": "" },
  {"hr": 1, "min": 60, "inMin": 0, "value": "" }
    
 ];
tObj.forEach(function(obj){
  if(obj.min > 0){
    if(obj.hr > 0){
     obj.inMin = (obj.hr * 60 + obj.min);
     obj.value = obj.hr + "hr" + obj.min + "mins";
    }else{
     if(obj.min === 60){
       obj.inMin = Math.floor(obj.min / 60);
       obj.value = obj.inMin + "hr";
     }else{
       obj.inMin = obj.min;
       obj.value = obj.min + "mins";
    }
   }
  }else{
    if(obj.hr > 0){
        obj.inMin = (obj.hr * 60);
        obj.value = obj.hr + "hr";
    }else{
        obj.inMin = 0;
        obj.value = obj.min + "mins";
      }
  }
   });
   console.log(tObj);
```

Comment: just return ((obj.hr*60) + obj.min);

Comment: The code you had before the edit seems to be just fine. The problem with the code after the edit is that `time_convert` doesn't return a value, so `element.conVal = time_convert(element);` will assign `undefined` to `element.conVal`. But you can see that the `inMin` value is correct. So, it seems the computation is fine. You just need to access the correct property, or change the property to what you want (which we don't know).

Comment: Before edit it gives correct answer only! but if tObj[2] has 1hr and 60minutes it give 1hr 60minutes not 2hrs!

Comment: Well, given that you are already storing time values as hours and minutes, I would consider an  input with `hours: 1, minutes: 60` as invalid. Where does the data come from? If you want to be able to handle that, you first have to convert hours+minutes to minutes and then convert minutes back to hours+minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, this should do the job:

```js
// SOLUTION TO THE EDITED QUESTION
const tObj2 = Object.freeze([{
    "hr": 0,
    "min": 30,
    "inMin": 0,
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "hr": 0,
    "min": 45,
    "inMin": 0,
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "hr": 0,
    "min": 50,
    "inMin": 0,
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "hr": 1,
    "min": 15,
    "inMin": 0,
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "hr": 1,
    "min": 30,
    "inMin": 0,
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "hr": 1,
    "min": 45,
    "inMin": 0,
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "hr": 2,
    "min": 0,
    "inMin": 0,
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "hr": 1,
    "min": 65,
    "inMin": 0,
    "value": ""
  }
]);

tObj2.forEach(item => {
  const hours = item.hr + Math.floor(item.min / 60);
  const hoursTxt = hours > 0 ?
    hours + (hours === 1 && 'hr' || 'hrs') :
    '';

  const minutes = item.min % 60;
  const minutesTxt = minutes + (minutes === 1 && 'min' || 'mins');

  const timeTxt = hoursTxt ?
    hoursTxt + ' ' + minutesTxt :
    minutesTxt;

  item.inMin = hours * 60 + minutes;
  item.value = timeTxt;
});

// SOLUTION TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION
const tObj = Object.freeze([{
    "hr": 0,
    "min": 30
  },
  {
    "hr": 0,
    "min": 60
  },
  {
    "hr": 1,
    "min": 0
  },
  {
    "hr": 1,
    "min": 45
  },
  {
    "hr": 2,
    "min": 45
  },
  {
    "hr": 0,
    "min": 60
  }
]);

const formattedTimes = tObj.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const hours = item.hr + Math.floor(item.min / 60);
  const hoursTxt = hours > 0 ?
    hours + (hours === 1 && 'hr' || 'hrs') :
    '';

  const minutes = item.min % 60;
  const minutesTxt = minutes + (minutes === 1 && 'min' || 'mins');

  const timeTxt = hoursTxt ?
    hoursTxt + ' ' + minutesTxt :
    minutesTxt;

  const timeObj = {
    value: hours * 60 + minutes,
    text: timeTxt
  }

  acc.push(timeObj);

  return acc
}, []);

//test
console.log('Solution to the edited question:', tObj2);
console.log('Solution to the original question:', formattedTimes);
```

I've been a bit verbose with the code, in the hope it is self-explanatory but it can be shortened a bit, if you want.

Comment: You nailed it, man! Thank you so much! 1st solution is what I needed and 2nd solution is also must be appreciated! Thank you all!